# jsf page submit beanName.value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a jsf page and it has Something like this

```
<p:inputText value='#{myBean.name}' />
<p:inputText value='#{myBean.lastName}' />
<p:button action='#{myBean.show} />
```

On MyBean.java i have this function

```
Public void show(){
System.out.print(MyBean.name + MyBean.lastName);
}
```

Name y lastName both have get and set methods but it only shows 'null null'

Any advice will be very apreciated, thank you

I'm working on Ibm Rational Workspace

Comment: Code contains too many red herrings. There are already at least 3 true technical mistakes and 2 potential functional mistakes which makes it impossible to get the code to run and end up in the described result. Please copypaste real tested code unmodified instead of using question editor as code editor as long as you're not capable of writing valid code from top of head.

Answer (score 0):

use commandButton instead :

```
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.show()}">
```